# Apache - Error 404 calling REST API /codeguard/users - PHP Laravel - CentOS 7

Tags: php, laravel, apache, rest, virtualhost

I'm trying to host 2 web sites using 1 IP,site uses laravel PHP routes, so i used Apache Alias approach and virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:443  >

# General setup for the virtual host, inherited from global configuration
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"

Alias "/development" "/var/www/html/develop/public"

Alias "/staging" "/var/www/html/staging/public"


# Use separate log files for the SSL virtual host; note that LogLevel
# is not inherited from httpd.conf.
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/prod_ssl_error_log
TransferLog /var/log/httpd/prod_ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn


<Directory "/var/www/html/develop/public">
             DirectoryIndex index.php
             AllowOverride All
             Order allow,deny
             Allow from all
     </Directory>




SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/1.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/1.key

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443  >

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/staging/public"

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/staging_ssl_error_log
TransferLog /var/log/httpd/staging_ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn

<Directory "/var/www/html/staging/public">
             DirectoryIndex index.php
             Options FollowSymLinks
             AllowOverride All
             Order allow,deny
             Allow from all
     </Directory>

 SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/1.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/1.key

</VirtualHost>
```

Both sites have public folder with index.php and .htaccess files

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteBase /~development
RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

When accessing https://server/development
and https://server/staging all works fine, i'm getting php page

but if trying https:/server/development/codeguard/users i'm getting error 404
and in log file

File does not exist: `/var/www/html/develop/public/codeguard/users`

codeguard/users indeed are not present but it works fine if i'm remove Alias directive

If i try https://server/development/index.php/codeguard/users/ then it works

But i have no any issues if assigning multiple IP's to Apache web server and binding these 2 addresses to each virtual host respectively - non-aliased url

I need to make https:/server/development/codeguard/users link works (without index.php)

I presume i need to edit .httacess file for both sites but have no clue what needs to be done.

Any help/hint is highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

i make it work for first virtual host (development) by editing .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase "/development/"


    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
   # RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]


    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php/
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

But using same congfiguration for second site ("/staging") fails with same error 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working, error was in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf file,  i had 2 `<Virtual Host *:443>` directives and only one should be defined, otherwise .htaccess for "second" site is ignored

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

# General setup for the virtual host, inherited from global configuration
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"



#ServerName www.example.com:443

# Use separate log files for the SSL virtual host; note that LogLevel
# is not inherited from httpd.conf.
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel debug



<Directory "/var/www/html/develop/public">
             DirectoryIndex index.php
             Options FollowSymLinks
             AllowOverride All
             Order allow,deny
             Allow from all
     </Directory>


Alias "/development" "/var/www/html/develop/public"





<Directory "/var/www/html/staging/public">
             DirectoryIndex index.php
             Options FollowSymLinks
             AllowOverride All
             Order allow,deny
             Allow from all
     </Directory>



Alias "/staging" "/var/www/html/staging/public"

</VirtualHost>
```

Then .htaccess for both sites started working